# Just me, or is the suggested edits font different?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When I was reviewing suggested edits, I noticed the font to be... different. Is it just me? I quite like the new font. It happens in some edits and in some it doesn't... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2415722)'s one where it happens to me.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Nope, can't see any difference. Maybe you see markdown difference?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope, I thought my eyes were fooling me. Updated.

Comment: Still nothing different. Screenshot maybe? (by the way, it wasn't too minor in my opinion)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Done. (It looked like it to me, as I at first thought all of it was in code formatting. Look at the pic)

Comment: You are viewing the markdown difference, it has different font than "rendered output" which is the default view.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You're right. I'm dumb. Should I delete this?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Nope. I'll give an answer and upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the markdown version - the not-rendered text that specifies the formatting for the post.

Since it's not rendered, it is shown as code. You'll need to switch from `markdown` to `rendered output` using the toggle directly above and to the left of the edit preview.